# Showing a Hidden DIV with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a div that starts out hidden:

```
<div id='deskView' style="display: none;">
```

How can i make it visible using jQuery on a button click?

Comment: I know that stackoverflow is a convenient place to get answers, but seriously that's like the simplest thing you can do with the framework. I'm not sure how you could get through 3 paragraphs of a tutorial without running across ".show()" and ".hide()".

Comment: show() wasn't working for me (which is why i posted the question) but it turns out it was a case sensitivity issue with my selector

Comment: This question is actually better than many. States what oo want's to accomplish, how to affect it, and shows relevant code, all in a concise manner. I'd rather see this than ' *why won't jQuery do what I want* ' questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at the API.

http://api.jquery.com/show/

Comment: +! i love docu refs!! it's like googeling :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#deskview').show();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#button_id').click(function() {
  $('#deskView').show();
});
```

Anyway - this is a good place to look for further information:
http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  $('#myButton').click(function(){
    $('#deskView').show();
  });

});
</script>

<div id="deskView" style="display: none;">
  desk  view
</div>

<input type="button" value="Click Me" id="myButton" />
```

Go through the [Tutorials](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials) -- it's worth it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button" value="Click" id="Button1" onClick="$('#deskView').show()" />
```